# Updating 'Age Group ID' by contacts DOB - MySQL + PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I was wondering how would be the best way to address the following:

I have a table called 'contacts', within this table I have 2 fields, contacts.age_group_id and contacts.DOB. The DOB field is regularly filled in but the age_group_id isn't and also it is something that will change as the contact gets older based on the current date and their DOB.

The age_group table is as follows:

age_group.id - int
age_group.name - varchar  (e.g. 65-70 years old - retirement database)

SAMPLE:

id: 1 - name: 65-70 years old
id: 2 - name: 71-75 years old
id: 3 - name: 76-80 years old

etc

I can easily put in more fields into the age_group table if needed but I do need to constantly update the contact.age_group_id field so it is current for the exported report.

Any suggestions how I can do this within a function of some sort?

I am using cakephp but it's more of a general PHP / MySQL question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My original thought was to put min_age and max_age in the age_group table, but that would require you to compute the user's age, then join that to the age_group table.  Computing for every row is not great (and can't be indexed).

So, here are two ideas:

1. store the start date and end date of each range in the agr_group table, so 65 years ago (today) would be 9/20/1947.  Compare that with the user's DOB.  The good news is that it would be fast, but you'd have to regenerate the dates every day.
2. compute and store the user's age.  Again, fast, but you'll have to regenerate even more data every day.

Oh, the third idea is to wait for a better idea :)